# Cross-origin AJAX request - XMLHttpRequest Exception 101

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cordova, cross-domain

I have Cordova app (`Cordova 6.0.0`) with `access origin *` and `HTTP API`(sending data through POST), which has `header Access-Control-Allow-Origin` set to `*`. API is running on domain https://api.stude.cz, so you can check it (yeah, i'm calling https from the app). Well, when i try to call api with jQuery synchronous AJAX from the app, i'm getting

```
{
    "readyState":0,
    "status":0,
    "statusText":"Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101"
}
```

It's JSON stringified, because Android Studio doesn't support displaying arrays in console. Do you know why? I spent lot of time with this...

My request:

```
function apiRequest(type, action, params) {
    var returnValue = false;
    console.log('started');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.stude.cz/' + type + '/' + action,
        type: 'post',
        async: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        data: params,
        success: function(data){
            returnValue = data;
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            returnValue = JSON.stringify({status:"error"});
        }
    });
    return(returnValue);
}
```

I tested with:

```
type = user
action = login
params = {email: -some email-, password: -some password-}
```

Comment: You need to provide more information about what you are doing and what happens. What, exactly, does the request look like? Is it a POST request or is it a preflight OPTIONS request? What Content-Type are you using? etc. What, exactly, does the response look like? What status is the server sending back to the client?

Comment: @Quetin I will add it in a minute. :)

Comment: Also please add which Cordova version you are using (cordova --version will tell you) as you may be hitting issues with Content Security Policy if you are using version 5 or higher.

Comment: @SimonPrickett Okay, i added it, and for you, i'm using 6.0.0 (the newest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it with removing and adding Android platform.

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```

I think that problem was in plugin whitelist or something like that, but thanks for help!